# How to harden the browser on an old iPad Air 1st Gen on iOS 12.5.5?

Tags: web-browser, ios

I have an old iPad Air 1st Generation with the latest supported iOS 12.5.5.

**How may I maximize its safety against system and browser vulnerabilities?** I guess I should not use Safari? So is Brave a better option and does it get updates?

Comment: It really doesn't make much difference which browser you use. Due to the restrictions Apple places on its App Store, third-party browser are just a skin on top of Safari's webkit.

Comment: While we can talk about the impacts of different browsers, we do not do product recommendations on this site, so I removed that part of the question.

Comment: @nobody so using 3rd party browser that get updates is not better than safari on ios 12.5.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Safari with AdGuard from the App Store is better, Other browsers don't really offer much on iOS as others have pointed out it uses the same WebKit and if the device is that old I am guessing it doesn't have a lot of storage, however to answer the rest of your question;

Use an Ad Blocker. AdGuard seems to be highly rated and widely used more than AdBlock on Apple. AdBlock Pro is good like AdGuard though.

There are some settings I would change on Safari. I would hide previews for websites, I don't quite trust website previews since it means it has to load some of the page to preview it. I don't think it is a major risk, but it is safer to hide previews and you did mention to maximize security. I would also disable safari suggestions, search engine suggestions, quick search and preloading of top hit.

There are some default settings Apple puts on, but you can make sure prevent cross site tracking is on and hide ip address from trackers.

Comment: thanks for tips, but you sure safari at ios 12.5.5 better than a 3rd party that gets updates ? Does safari get updates or fixes at old ios without ios update ?

Comment: No, Safari gets updated with iOS updates.